# NodeJS/Express: PUT and body parser, body object empty

Tags: node.js, express, put, body-parser

I write a simple rest api for a blog. I have the following code (main file):

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
var express = require('express'); 
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var database = require('./config/database');
var app = express(); 
mongoose.connect(database.url);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(express.static('public'));

mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
    console.log('database connection established');
});

// Routes
app.use('/api/blog', require('./routes/blogroutes.js').router); 

// Start
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on port ', port); 
});
```

The file `blogroutes.js` looks like the following (extract):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); 

var BlogEntry = require('../models/blogEntry');

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    next();
});

router.route('/entry/:year/:month/:day/:nr')
    //.get(...).delete(...)
    .put(function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.body); 
    });

router.post('/entry', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); 
}); 

module.exports = {router: router};
```

The problem now is the following: When I call in the PowerShell `curl -uri http://localhost:8080/api/blog/entry/2016/3/2/3 -method put -body @{title='my first entry';text='Lorem ipsum'}`, the console output is `{}`. When I call in the PowerShell `curl -uri http://localhost:8080/api/blog/entry -method post -body @{title='my first entry';text='Lorem ipsum'}`, the console output is as expected `{ text: 'Wonderful', title: 'My second bike trip' }`. Do you have any idea why and how can I access the put body?

Comment: Did you try adding `console.log(req.headers['content-type'])` in your `PUT` route handler to see what `Content-Type` is being sent?

Comment: add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` to your `curl` call to your service, see if that fixes it

Comment: console.log(...content-type...) returns undefined. The -H parameter doesn't work in this PowerShell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't look like you're using *real* cURL, but instead it seems to be something like Powershell's `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet, [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) for `Invoke-WebRequest` specifically mentions that the `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will only be sent for `POST` requests. So you will need to explicitly set the `Content-Type` for non-`POST` requests by specifying an additional command-line option: `-ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for this insight! :)